# Calculate NDSI and display pixels only greater than 0.4

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

To this code I want just calculate NDSI and display pixels only greater than 0.4 but I am unable to do so.
How can I do this?

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2');
var urban = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-kskbss/assets/Beas_shapfile');
var chandrab = urban.geometry();

// Update the visualization parameters to use only the 'SR_B5' band
var singleBandVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 30000,
  bands: ['SR_B5', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B3'], 
};

// Filter and clip the image to the feature collection geometry
var filtered = s2.filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-09-01', '2019-09-15'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(chandrab));

var image = filtered.median(); 
var clipped = image.clip(chandrab);

// Calculate NDSI using the correct formula: (B3 - B5) / (B3 + B5)
var ndsi = clipped.expression(
  '(B3 - B5) / (B3 + B5)',
  {
    B3: clipped.select('SR_B3'),
    B5: clipped.select('SR_B5')
  }
).rename('NDSI');

// Visualization parameters for NDSI
var ndsiVis = {
  min: -1,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']
};

// Add the NDSI layer to the map
Map.addLayer(ndsi, ndsiVis, 'NDSI');

// Apply a threshold of 0.4 to identify snow pixels
var snow = ndsi.gt(-0.4).rename('snow');

// Add the snow layer to the map
Map.addLayer(snow, {palette: 'white,black'}, 'Snow Above Threshold');

// Reduce with ee.Reducer.histogram()
var reducer = snow.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(),
  geometry: chandrab,
  scale: 30,
  bestEffort: true
});

// Extract the snow pixels count
var dict = ee.Dictionary(reducer.get('snow'));
var histogram = dict.get('histogram');
var list = ee.List(histogram);
var snowCount = ee.Number(list.get(0));


// Print the snow count and area
print('Snow Pixel Count:', snowCount);
```

Comment: Hi @koneru, what were the results you were expecting and what do you actually get as a result?That would go some way to pinpointing what the problem is. At the moment it's just code, we don't know whether it works because it's not clear what you were trying to achieve. Can you reduce the example into something smaller with an expected and actual result to demonstrate the problem more clearly?